# Arc complex characterization of braids with trivial closure

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, braid-groups

A braid $\beta\in B_n,$ the braid group with $n$ strands, viewed as the mapping class group $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb{D}_n)$ of the disk with $n$ punctures is trivial if and only if $\beta$ acts trivially on the set of isotopy classes of arcs $\gamma$ with one endpoint on $\partial \mathbb{D}_n$ and another one on a puncture.

Is there any similar arc complex characterization of braids $\beta\in B_n$ whose closure $\hat{\beta}$ is a trivial knot ? By that I mean any statement of the form "$\hat{\beta}$ is a trivial knot if and only if the action of $\beta$ on the set of isotopy classes of arcs has such and such property"

Answer (score 2):

Good question, but I think the answer is somewhere between "we don't know" and "probably not".  [Dynnikov](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208153) has a beautiful result related to this, as do [Birman and Menasco](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310279) and [Ghiggini-Lisca](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2148).  But none of these do what you actually want.